# "OpenPose is not defined" issue on Windows10 using Python3.7

Tags: python-3.x, openpose

I get the same error `NameError: name 'OpenPose' is not defined` mentioned in an [issue](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/issues/709) in Openpose's Github repo but on Windows platform instead. I can't import openpose either.
Although, I can import pyopenpose and all 'tutorial_api_python' examples work.

I tried `cmake install .` instead of `sudo make install`, by following the [doc/deployment.md](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/master/doc/deployment.md) instructions, but still no luck.

Am I supposed to work through pyopenpose Wrapper `opWrapper = op.WrapperPython()` to get this working?